# play json in scala: deserializing json with unknown fields without losing them

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

consider i have a json as following:

```
 {
  "a": "aa",
  "b": "bb",
  "c": "cc",
  "d": "dd", // unknown in advance
  "e": { //unknown in advance
    "aa": "aa"
  }
}
```

i know for sure that the json will contain a,b,c but i've no idea what other fields this json may contain.

i want to serialize this JSON into a case class containing a,b,c but on the other hand not to lose the other fields (save them in a map so the class will be deserialized to the same json as received).

ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to capture the "unknown" fields in a `Map[String,JsValue]`, from which you can later extract values if you need them.

```
case class MyClass(a: String, b: String, c: String, extra: Map[String, JsValue])
implicit val reads: Reads[MyClass] = (
  (__ \ "a").read[String] and
  (__ \ "b").read[String] and
  (__ \ "c").read[String] and
  __.read[Map[String, JsValue]]
    .map(_.filterKeys(k => !Seq("a", "b", "c").contains(k)))
)(MyClass.apply _)

// Result:
// MyClass(aa,bb,cc,Map(e -> {"aa":"aa"}, d -> "dd"))
```

Likewise, you can do a `Writes` or a `Format` like so:

```
// And a writes...
implicit val writes: Writes[MyClass] = (
  (__ \ "a").write[String] and
  (__ \ "b").write[String] and
  (__ \ "c").write[String] and
  __.write[Map[String, JsValue]]
)(unlift(MyClass.unapply _))

// Or combine the two...
implicit val format: Format[MyClass] = (
  (__ \ "a").format[String] and
  (__ \ "b").format[String] and
  (__ \ "c").format[String] and
  __.format[Map[String, JsValue]](Reads
    .map[JsValue].map(_.filterKeys(k => !Seq("a", "b", "c").contains(k))))
)(MyClass.apply, unlift(MyClass.unapply))
```

Note: it looks a bit confusing because you give the `format` for `Map[String,JsValue]` an explicit `Reads` as an argument (`Reads.map`), which you then transform (using the `.map` *method*) to remove the already-captures values.

Comment: and how does the Writes should look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `Reads` for this, something like:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class MyData(a: String, b: String, c:String, other: Map[String, JsValue])

object MyData {
  val abcReader: Reads[(String, String, String)] = (
    (JsPath \ "a").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "b").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "c").read[String]
  ).tupled

  implicit val reader: Reads[MyData] = Reads { json =>
    abcReader.reads(json).map {
      case (a, b, c) =>
        val other = json.as[JsObject].value -- Seq("a", "b", "c")
        MyData(a, b, c, other.toMap)
    }
  }
}
```